# Overflow: hidden doesn't work for image

Tags: html, css, height, width

I am using the following code in html to display and image. I want it to 'scale to fill' where the height is the browser height and the width scales based on the height. I want to hide all overflow to prevent the div that follows from losing its content. This is the code I am trying to use:

```
<div id="image1">
<img src="http://googledrive.com/host/0By-qb7dZ_m5feE94MkcwSWxLckU"/>
<style>
#image1{
overflow: hidden;
width: auto
height: 100vh;
}
</style>
</div>
```

If anyone has any ideas then that would be great.

Thanks

Comment: This worked mostly but stopped the image from resizing when the page was scaled:  <div id="image1">
<img src="http://googledrive.com/host/0By-qb7dZ_m5feE94MkcwSWxLckU"/>
<style>
#image1{
width: auto;
height: 100vh;
overflow: hidden;
}
</style>
</div>

Answer (score 1):

Change the width to 100% and the height to auto. Then redefine the img style and move the two properties there.

```
#image1 {
     overflow: hidden;
}
img {
     width: 100%;
     height: auto;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I dont know if i exactly know what you mean, but try to set your width to 100%, that should cover the div.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the overflow by moving `overflow: hidden;` to a redefined `body` style.

For the 'scale to fill' part of your problem, add `img` to your `#image1` style so that the image is affected by the style and not the div itself. Set the `width` to `100%` and the `height` to `auto` so that the image width is the same as the browser's, and the image height adjusts automatically and proportionally on window resize.

```css
body {
 overflow: hidden; 
}
#image1 img {
 width: 100%;
 height: auto;
}
```

Comment: This looked like it might have worked but the body tag applies this to all of my content which is inside body and in doing so blocks the other divs from being seen for some reason.